# stop sidekiq worker perform method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have an `begin rescue` block in my worker's `perform` method like this

```
begin
  HTTParty.get(url)
rescue
  ## call failed for some reason, log and stop performing
  break
end
## do more stuff here with the result of the call if it didn't fail
## this can fail too so a further
  begin
    ##would be cumbersome
  rescue
  end
```

however I get an `Invalid break (SyntaxError)`

Is there another way to tell sidekiq that this job is essentially finished? I don't want it to retry but rather just quit completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return:

```
begin
  HTTParty.get(url)
rescue => e
  logger.warn(e.message)
  return
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any break. If the code inside the begin fails, the execution will be halted and the content inside the `rescue` block is executed. To silently ignore and return, simply leave the content of the rescue empty.

```
def perform
  begin
    HTTParty.get(url)
  rescue
    ## call failed for some reason, log and stop performing
  end
end
```

You can also shorten the method

```
def perform
  HTTParty.get(url)
rescue
  ## call failed for some reason, log and stop performing
end
```

You may want to explicitly rescue only certain exceptions. I'm not sure what you want to rescue (it depends on what HTTParty can raise).

```
def perform
  HTTParty.get(url)
rescue WhateverError
  ## call failed for some reason, log and stop performing
end
```

Here's an example

```
def perform
  HTTParty.get(url)
rescue WhateverError => e
  Rails.logger.error "Kaboom! #{e.message}"
end
```

Comment: well I have a lot of code that gets executed after the HTTParty call (some of which can also fail). I don't want to have cascading code layers of lots of begin rescue end blocks but rather just to wrap the fail-prone code in a begin and rescue with quitting the peform

Comment: If you use a single rescue statement at the end as I shown you without any exception type, all (standard) exceptions will be rescued.